# Python MYSQL Query throws programming syntax error 1064

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to send an UPDATE query to my DB, with the following specifications:

```
    markets_string = "Coingecko, Coinmarketcap"
    hashy = "e491bddae29c9fb6dd7666e25e34d6d642a05701"

    mycursor.execute("""
            UPDATE %s 
            SET markets = %s
            WHERE id = %s
            """, (source, markets_string, hashy))
```

However, I get the following syntax error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''coinplace'
            SET markets = 'Coingecko, Coinmarketcap'
   ' at line 1
```

Execuse me before hand if this question has already been answered, I googled myself, but couldn't find any solution.

EDIT: I'm using mysql.connector

Comment: I'm going to guess it is this `UPDATE %s`. You don't say what MySQL library you are using, but generally passing a parameter in as an identifier(table name in this case)  is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver, I edited the question to add the library I'm using. I need to use it this way since I'm iterating over a dataset on which there are different table names of my DB. How could I make this work the most efficient way possible?

Comment: None library allows this. You set the parameter as string `'%s'`, so its value is wrapped with quotes `'`, and server treates it as string literal-constant which is not legal in this place.

Comment: Furthermore, iterating over tablenames (or database names) usually implies a poor schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming source is the table name and is 'coinplace';

```
source = 'coinplace'

qry_str = "UPDATE " + source + " " +  """
SET markets = %s
WHERE id = %s

print(qry_str)                                                                                                                                                            
UPDATE coinplace 
SET markets = %s
WHERE id = %s

mycursor.execute(qry_str, (markets_string, hashy))
"""
```

This does allow for SQL injection because of the use of string concatenation for the table name, so you would want to be sure of the origin of the value for `source`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

test as follows:

query = "UPDATE %s SET markets = %s WHERE id = %s"
values = source, markets_string, hashy

mycursor.execute(query, (values, ))